# How to disable other div's dropping functionality if the user clicks on one of the droppable div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, shopping-cart

I am very new to jquery. Presently i am working on a project of shopping cart where there are three types of items(item1,item2,item3) and three bags(bag1,bag2,bag3) and one shopping cart such as bag1 accepts item1,item2,item3 , bag2 accepts item2,item3 and bag3 accepts only item3 on drop which I have developed so far.

Now i want to add additional functionality such as the user should first select any one of the bag(example bag1) and then try dropping items into the bag1 such that  other two bags dropping functionality should be disable(other bags should not accept any item even if it is acceptable by that bag) and also reverse if user selects other bags.

I tried all possible ways.Any one out there plz try it.

**http://jsfiddle.net/Vwu37/15/**

html

```
<div class="bag1" ><p>bag1</p></div>
<div class="bag2" > <p>bag2</p></div>
<div class="bag3" ><p>bag3</p></div>
<div class="item1"><p>item1_1</p></div>
<div class="item1"><p>item2_1</p></div>
<div class="item1"><p>item2_1</p></div>
```

js

```
 $('.bag1').droppable({
                accept: '.item1,.item2,.item3',
                 onDragEnter:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
                },
                onDragLeave:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
                },
                onDrop:function(e,source){
                    var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                    var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
                    addProduct(name, parseFloat(price.split('$')[1]));
                }
            });

            $('.bag2').droppable({
                accept: '.item2,.item3',
                onDragEnter:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
                },
                onDragLeave:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
                },
                onDrop:function(e,source){
                    var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                    var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
                   }
            });

            $('.bag3').droppable({
                accept: '.item3',
                onDragEnter:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
                },
                onDragLeave:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
                },
                onDrop:function(e,source){
                    var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                    var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
                                    }
            });
```

Comment: "I tried all possible ways" - obviously you didn't or it would be working now. Perhaps you should include some of the possible ways you tried.

Comment: I mean searching other duplicates and i am very new to jquery.If u can plz help me.

Comment: @Heybey How do you want users to 'select' a bag? By clicking on it? You need to be more clear

Comment: @Zeaklous yes by clicking it.sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @JonnySooter have u tried.

Comment: @Zeaklous have u tried too.No answer yet from any one.You guys please try it if u can.

Comment: It's not our job to code the whole thing for you, but to help you in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do in your position is instead of having three different classes (`bag1`, `bag2`, `bag3`), I would create a new class called `bag` and give each of the bags that class and then specify any other CSS specific to each one in another class called `one`, `two` and `three`. So for example the first bag would become `<div class="bag two" style="...`. I would then add a jQuery function like this

```
$('.bag').click(function() {
    if($('.selected').length > 0 && !$(this).hasClass('selected'))
    { // Checks to see if there is a selected and if the clicked one is selected
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        // Allows a bag to be toggled when clicked
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        // If there is no bag `selected` then make the clicked one selected
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

and also create some CSS for the `selected` class for users to know which one is clicked

```
.selected {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

Then you can set the rules for whether or not something is dragable or not based on what is `selected`. This part is pseudocode

```
 if($('.bag.one').hasClass('selected'))
 {
     // Allow things to be dragged to only bag one
 }
 if($('.bag.two').hasClass('selected'))
 {
     // Allow things to be dragged only to bag two
 }
 if($('.bag.three').hasClass('selected'))
 {
     // Allow things to be dragged only to bag three
 }
```

Your code is too massive for us to implement the whole thing for you. This should give you the correct direction to go towards. Please comment if there is anything else I can help you with

***-----GIGANTIC EDIT-----***

(I shouldn't have worked this hard on correcting your situation but I feel bad for your position so I did)

After some massive changes to correcting the formatting of your code, optimizing it for reuse (and removing hundreds of lines of unneeded code in the process), moving the if statements I created earlier into a `setInterval` to check to update it with current information, and correcting much of your poor CSS, I came up with [this rough update](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/Vwu37/24/)

Here is the code for that:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="body">
    <div class="bag one">
        Bag 1
        <img src="images/sb1.jpg" height="50" width="50" />
    </div>

    <div class="bag two">
        Bag 2
        <img src="images/sb2.jpg" height="50" width="50" />
    </div>

    <div class="bag three">
        Bag 3
        <img src="images/sb3.jpg" height="50" width="50" />
    </div>

    <div class="products" style="width: 120px; height: 100px; left: 23px; top: 120px;">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#" class="item one">
                    <img src="images/shirt2.gif" height="45" width="45"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>item1_1</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="products" style="width: 120px; height: 100px; left: 30px; top: 225px;">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#" class="item two">
                    <img src="images/shoes1.gif" height="45" width="45"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>item2_1</p>
                        <p>Price:$30</p>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="products" style="width: 120px; height: 144px; left: 34px; top: 342px;">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#" class="item three">
                    <img src="images/shirt2.gif" height="45" width="45"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>item3_1</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="cart" style="left: 200px; top: 150px; height: 300px; width: 237px">
        <div class="ctitle">Shopping Cart</div>
        <div style="background:#fff">
            <table id="cartcontent1" fitColumns="true" style="width1:300px;height:auto;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th field="name" width=140>Name</th>
                        <th field="quantity" width=60 align="right">Quantity</th>
                        <th field="price" width=60 align="right">Price</th>
                        <th field="remove" width=60 align="right">Remove</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <p class="total">Total: $0</p>
        <div class="ctitle" style="position:absolute;bottom:10px"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- CSS -->
.bag {
    width:80px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
.products {
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    background:#fafafa;
}
.products ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0px;
}
.products li {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}

.item {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.item img {
    border:1px solid #333;
}
.item p {
    margin:0;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    color:#c3c3c3;
}
.cart {
    position:absolute;
    width:260px;
    height:100%;
    background:#ccc;
    padding:0px 10px;
}
.ctitle {
    text-align:center;
    color:#555;
    font-size:18px;
    padding:10px;
}
.auto-style3 {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 260px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.selected {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}

<!-- Javascript/jQuery-->
var data = {
    "total": 0,
        "rows": []
};
var totalCost = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cartcontent1').datagrid({
        singleSelect: true
    });


    $('.item').draggable({
        revert: true,
        proxy: 'clone',
        onStartDrag: function () {
            $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
            $(this).draggable('proxy').css('z-index', 10);
        },
        onStopDrag: function () {
            $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'move';
        }
    });


    $('.bag').click(function () {
        if ($('.selected').length > 0 && !$(this).hasClass('selected')) { // Checks to see if there is a selected and if the clicked one is selected
            $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            // Allows a bag to be toggled when clicked
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        } else {
            // If there is no bag `selected` then make the clicked one selected
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });
});

var check = setInterval(function() {    
    if ($('.bag.one').hasClass('selected')) {

        $('.bag.one').droppable({
            accept: '.item.one,.item.two,.item.three',
            onDragEnter: function (e, source) {
                $(source).draggable('options').cursor = 'auto';
            },
            onDragLeave: function (e, source) {
                $(source).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
            },
            onDrop: function (e, source) {
                var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
                addProduct(name, parseFloat(price.split('$')[1]));
            }
        });
    } else if ($('.bag.two').hasClass('selected')) {
        $('.bag.two').droppable({
            accept: '.item.two,.item.three',
            onDragEnter: function (e, source) {
                $(source).draggable('options').cursor = 'auto';
            },
            onDragLeave: function (e, source) {
                $(source).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
            },
            onDrop: function (e, source) {
                var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
            }
        });
    } else if ($('.bag.three').hasClass('selected')) {
        // Allow things to be dragged only to bag three
        $('.bag.three').droppable({
            accept: '.item.three',
            onDragEnter: function (e, source) {
                $(source).draggable('options').cursor = 'auto';
            },
            onDragLeave: function (e, source) {
                $(source).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
            },
            onDrop: function (e, source) {
                var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
            }
        });
    }
}, 100);

function addProduct(name, price) {
    var totalQuantity = sumQuantity(data);

    if (totalQuantity < 8) {
        function add() {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.total; i++) {
                var row = data.rows[i];
                if (row.name == name) {
                    row.quantity += 1;
                    return;
                }
            }
            data.total += 1;
            data.rows.push({
                name: name,
                quantity: 1,
                price: price,
                remove: '<a href="#" class="remove" onclick="removeProduct(this, event)">X</a>'
            });
        }
        add();
        totalCost += price;
        $('#cartcontent1').datagrid('loadData', data);
        $('div.cart .total').html('Total: $' + totalCost);
    } else {
        alert('cannot have more than 8 items');
    }
}

function removeProduct(el, event) {
    var tr = $(el).closest('tr');
    var name = tr.find('td[field=name]').text();
    var price = tr.find('td[field=price]').text();
    var quantity = tr.find('td[field=quantity]').text();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.total; i++) {
        var row = data.rows[i];
        if (row.name == name) {
            data.rows.splice(i, 1);
            data.total--;
            break;
        }
    }
    totalCost -= price * quantity;
    $('#cartcontent1').datagrid('loadData', data);
    $('div.cart .total').html('Total: $' + totalCost);
}

function sumQuantity(data) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.total; i++) {
        sum += data.rows[i].quantity;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

It still needs to be fixed in that you must disable the others using something like `$(this).droppable("option", "disabled", true);` and re-enable it when it is `selected`, and also deal with bags two and three, but this gives you a lot more to work with

Quick question: Are you going to have multiple carts for the other bags? I'm not quite sure why you have three bags...

**Take Aways for you... (hopefully):**

1. ***LEARN HOW TO CODE ONLINE***. This will make problem solving, optimizing, and simply doing everything much better. Use tutorial websites like CodeAcademy to learn more. You *NEED* a basis in web coding to code on the web
2. **Try to reuse code where you can.** If you're going to have more than one element of the same type that all have very very similar characteristics, try to use a class as opposed to hard coding each one - that's the purpose of a class
3. **Try it yourself before asking others.** When you asked the question you provided zero evidence that you had tried to do it yourself. You should work on a problem for days before asking a question here unless you're *100%* sure you're not going to get it
4. **Keep your code clean**. Use spacing correctly and make sure all your `()` and `{}` line up. You did well at naming your variables recognizable things so that's good
5. **Check your code for errors**. When looking through it I found several missing `</div>`s, misspellings, a missing `</li>` and other errors that can be fixed easily. That's just carelessness
6. **Style your elements using the CSS panel in jsFiddle or in `<style>` tags on web pages**. This makes it a lot easier to see exactly what's affecting what. In-line styling should be avoided at all costs
7. **Learn to utilize your browser's element inspector and console log**. It makes some problems very easy to fix and helps you see exactly what styles elements have while running among many other things.

This post has gone way too long now, but I hope that I've helped. Really, you do need to get a stronger basis in your javascript, HTML, CSS, and jQuery knowledge before continuing work. That should be your top priority right now.

In closing (since this feels like a letter):

***"If debugging is the process of removing bugs, then programming 
must be the process of putting them in." - Edsger Dijkstra***

You must have been programming a lot ^^

***-----FINAL EDIT-----***

I really have worked too hard on this. You owe me something.

Anywho, I restructured the entire thing again to get it fully functional. I had to create a type of [mini-version](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/TgQTP/166/) to make sure my concepts were correct. It turns out I simply had a couple of extra data-scopes in my HTML...

The only thing I don't have working is the remove button (the X in the table). I have no earthly idea why that's stopped working, I triple checked all the code for it is the same as before.

Updated code:

```
/* HTML */
<div id="body">
    <div class="bag one" data-scope="one, two, three">Bag 1
        <img src="images/sb1.jpg" height="50" width="50" />
    </div>
    <div class="bag two" data-scope="two, three">Bag 2
        <img src="images/sb2.jpg" height="50" width="50" />
    </div>
    <div class="bag three" data-scope="three">Bag 3
        <img src="images/sb3.jpg" height="50" width="50" />
    </div>
    <div class="products" style="width: 120px; height: 100px; left: 23px; top: 120px;">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#" class="item one" data-scope="one">
                    <img src="images/shirt2.gif" height="45" width="45"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>item1_1</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="products" style="width: 120px; height: 100px; left: 30px; top: 225px;">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#" class="item two" data-scope="two">
                    <img src="images/shoes1.gif" height="45" width="45"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>item2_1</p>
                        <p>Price:$30</p>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="products" style="width: 120px; height: 144px; left: 34px; top: 342px;">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#" class="item three" data-scope="three">
                    <img src="images/shirt2.gif" height="45" width="45"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>item3_1</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="cart" style="left: 200px; top: 150px; height: 300px; width: 237px">
        <div class="ctitle">Shopping Cart</div>
        <div style="background:#fff">
            <table id="cartcontent1" fitColumns="true" style="width1:300px;height:auto;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th field="name" width=140>Name</th>
                        <th field="quantity" width=60 align="right">Quantity</th>
                        <th field="price" width=60 align="right">Price</th>
                        <th field="remove" width=60 align="right">Remove</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <p class="total">Total: $0</p>
        <div class="ctitle" style="position:absolute;bottom:10px"></div>
    </div>
</div>

/* CSS */
.bag {
    width:80px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
.products {
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    background:#fafafa;
}
.products ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0px;
}
.products li {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}
.item {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.item img {
    border:1px solid #333;
}
.item p {
    margin:0;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    color:#c3c3c3;
}
.cart {
    position:absolute;
    width:260px;
    height:100%;
    background:#ccc;
    padding:0px 10px;
}
.ctitle {
    text-align:center;
    color:#555;
    font-size:18px;
    padding:10px;
}
.auto-style3 {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 260px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.selected {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}

/* javascript/jQuery */
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = {
        "total": 0,
            "rows": []
    };
    var totalCost = 0;
    $('#cartcontent1').datagrid({
        singleSelect: true
    });

    $('.item').each(function (index, div) {
        var scope = $(this).attr('data-scope');
        $(div).draggable({
            revert: true,
            proxy: 'clone',
            onStartDrag: function () {
                $('.bag:not(.bag[data-scope*=' + scope + '])').droppable('disable');
                if($('.selected').length > 0)
                    $(':not(.selected)').droppable('disable');
                $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
                $(this).draggable('proxy').css('z-index', 10);
            },
            onStopDrag: function () {
                $('.bag').droppable('enable');
                $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'move';
            }
        });
    });

    $('.bag').click(function () {
        if ($('.selected').length > 0 && !$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });

    $('.bag').droppable({
        onDrop: function (e, source) {
            var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
            var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
            addProduct(name, parseFloat(price.split('$')[1]));
            $(source.draggable).remove();
            $('.bag').droppable('enable');
        }
    });

    function addProduct(name, price) {
        var totalQuantity = sumQuantity(data);

        if (totalQuantity < 8) {
            function add() {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.total; i++) {
                    var row = data.rows[i];
                    if (row.name == name) {
                        row.quantity += 1;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                data.total += 1;
                data.rows.push({
                    name: name,
                    quantity: 1,
                    price: price,
                    remove: '<a href="#" class="remove" onclick="removeProduct(this, event)">X</a>'
                });
            }
            add();
            totalCost += price;
            $('#cartcontent1').datagrid('loadData', data);
            $('div.cart .total').html('Total: $' + totalCost);
        } else {
            alert('cannot have more than 8 items');
        }
    }

    function removeProduct(el, event) {
        var tr = $(el).closest('tr');
        var name = tr.find('td[field=name]').text();
        var price = tr.find('td[field=price]').text();
        var quantity = tr.find('td[field=quantity]').text();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.total; i++) {
            var row = data.rows[i];
            if (row.name == name) {
                data.rows.splice(i, 1);
                data.total--;
                break;
            }
        }
        totalCost -= price * quantity;
        $('#cartcontent1').datagrid('loadData', data);
        $('div.cart .total').html('Total: $' + totalCost);
    }

    function sumQuantity(data) {
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.total; i++) {
            sum += data.rows[i].quantity;
        }
        return sum;
    }
});
```

This is all I'm going to do for you, it's far more than you deserve especially since you provided 0 help since posting the question. Don't expect this much from anyone ever.

[Here is the last Fiddle I'm touching](http://jsfiddle.net/Vwu37/35/). Have a good day

Comment: can you update my jsfiddle. i know its my job to code but as i said u i am very new to jquery its difficult for me and not for developers like u all.plz be kind to me.

Comment: `"Your code is too massive for us to implement the whole thing for you. This should give you the correct direction to go towards."` All you have to do is make the changes I specified and copy over the already implemented code to put within the if statements. If you don't know jQuery well you should *Go Learn It*... Otherwise you'll ask too many questions for us to answer and be helpless

Comment: We're not here to do your work for you. Only to provide help when you're stuck, which I have provided. I've even done most of it for you

Comment: how can i give two different classes to the same bag?

Comment: With the syntax I provided - using a space to separate each. ***You need to learn the basics of web programming***. Find some tutorials to teach you like [CodeAcademy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks) or many other sites to help you learn

Comment: okay i will try it out and let u know if any problem.thanks for your support.

Comment: If you find an answer has satisfactorily helped you solve your issue, you can click the check mark next to the answer to mark it as correct which will also show the question has been answered

Comment: okay but i will then not be able to contact u through comments.i will mark it as answer once i am done.again thanks a lot i appreciate u.

Comment: Sure you can. Or you can email me, which is on my profile page. I'm quite willing to help, you simply must know what you're doing first

Comment: Thanks a lot for boosting energy in me with your support.i will try hard to code it right.

Comment: Your javascript is broken. All of the () and {} do not match. That's why it's not doing anything. Give me a second, I'll clean it up for you. You should get in the habit of making good, clean code in the first place

Comment: You're code is so broken xD I have to fix the HTML, CSS, and javascript. You really ***NEED*** to get better at coding...

Comment: i am  sorry for the difficulty u are facing with my code to fix i will keep your advise on the top.

Comment: It's because the if statements were checked on page load and at no other time. I had to put them in a setInterval to have them check if the condition is met. I'm updating my answer now to tell of the changes I made

Comment: Updated. Hope it helps

Comment: ya helped a lot.u dont know what u have done for me.respect u.hats off.but items dropped in bag2 are not displayed.i have only one cart. but if it is not possible to display with one cart then suggest me to use three carts.

Comment: thanks a lot again feel like read your post again and again.such a nice post.

Comment: I can look at it more when I get home, but I have projects of my own to complete xD Try things yourself and let me know tomorrow what you're still having trouble with

Comment: i fixed the above problem  http://jsfiddle.net/Vwu37/26/   but now the code is working well only for the first time when page loads.also when we first time drag items and then select the bag and then try dropping its not working.do u have a solution for this.only if u have time plz help me.i am really struggling only two days are left to submit my project.

Comment: I'm still getting some errors, but I made a little improvement http://jsfiddle.net/Vwu37/28/

Comment: It happens when an object that is not suppose to go into the bag is dropped on the bag. I'm not sure how to prevent it

Comment: I posted my own SO question on the issue, hopefully they will come up with the solution soon. I'll look at it again tomorrow

Comment: aww zeaklous you are doing so much for much me thanks a lot.i have no words to express my feeling.

Comment: no one answered our code breaking question.if you want me to post the same question from my account i will post it.do u want me to post the question?

Comment: No, if no one answers mine then they don't know either. Reposts of questions are not accepted on StackOverflow

Comment: I'm working on it again now and you should be as well. Don't just ask others and let them do the work, WORK ON IT YOURSELF

Comment: Updated it for a final time. You can fix the last error. Have a good day

Comment: Zeaklous thanks a lot.i am very happy to know people like u also exists.you are the best in the world.thank u soo much.

Comment: If you ever feel like donating to me feel free, haha

Comment: in future once i make money i will remember u(u deserve more than that).hahaha too good to have a friend like u.at present i can just pray to god for your success.i know u will be a great developer one day.u r admirable.i can say u are the best. thanks for every thing.thank u so much.